# Need driver for an Epson WF-3620 printer

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

Does anyone know where I can get an Ubuntu driver for the Epson WF-3620 printer? The "linux drivers" page they send me to has download buttons but they don't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [Epson download page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).
Enter **WF-3620** as product name and choose **Linux** as operating system.

The search result page will give you three download links. Click on each of them. You will get new windows or tabs. Change to them. Scroll down until the end of the relevant driver download pages. Click the accept button and scroll down again.  There you click again on the download button of your matching ***.deb** file. Download and install them.

But beware, unfortunately not all features are supported by these generic drivers

Comment: When you get the printer up and running you may find you don't have access to the scan facility. Downloading Simple Scan from the Ubuntu Software Centre should allow you access to this important feature.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Ubuntu Software Center" and install package `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr`
2. Then add the printer through GUI and it should identify the printer and locate the driver immediately.

For scanning use Ubuntu-included scanning program. For better quality printing you have to change paper in "Printer Properties"->"Printer Options" you need to select under "Media Type": choose "plain papers-Standard-Vivid" in place of "plain papers-standard"

All works like a charm for me on Ubuntu 14.04 with this setup.

Comment: Have you got it connected via USB for scanning to work?